# highlight glossaries entries on page

Tags: formatting, glossaries, highlighting

I want to highlight my glossaries entries with bold or italic formatting.

I have used the following command but then the whole document is very colorful what I didn't want to have it like this.

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

I define my definitions like this:

```
\newglossaryentry{fps}{
  name=Frame per second,
  description= {
  TEXT..... }
}
```

And I reference this entry in the content with `\gls{fps}`.

How can I highlight in this example the word ***Frame per Second*** in the text

Comment: Try `\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\textbf{\em #1}}` or `\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\textbf{\itshape #1}}`

Comment: @NicolaTalbot This works perfect for my!

Comment: You can also use colour if you wish e.g. if you wanted blue for these but not for all links.

Answer (score 1):

(Converting my comment into an answer.)

You can redefine `\glstextformat`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{fps}{
  name=Frame per second,
  description={TEXT.....}
}

\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\textbf{\em #1}}

\begin{document}

\gls{fps}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document with term in bold italic]

Or (as mentioned by @cfr) you can add colour:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{fps}{
  name=Frame per second,
  description={TEXT.....}
}

\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\textbf{\color{blue}\em #1}}

\begin{document}

\gls{fps}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document with term displayed in bold italic blue text]